# Add multiple timer with for loop C#

Tags: c#, for-loop

I need 40 timers in my program but I want to create these dynamically.

```
System.Timers.Timer timermatrix1=new System.Timers.Timer();
timermatrix1.Enabled = true;
timermatrix1.Interval = 10;
timermatrix1.Elapsed += Timermatrix1_Elapsed;

private void Timermatrix1_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
         .....
    }
```

This code can create one timer but I need 40.So How can I do?

Comment: Please learn about arrays and Lists, then come back

Comment: @Thomas I know arrays and lists but I dont know how to change timers' name dynamically

Comment: Why does your timer need a name? Who shall read that name?

Comment: We see nothing in terms of a `List<Timer>` or, if you really want to access them by a name string `Dictionary<string, Timer>` in your code so far.. The more interesting aprt comes when coding the assumably diiferent events..

Comment: @Thomas I need name of timer.Because How can I assing Enableb=true or Interval of this timer Or Elapsed Event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an array and initialize them in a loop:

```
System.Timers.Timer[] timerMatrix = new System.Timers.Timer[40];

for(int i=0; i < 40; i++){
    timerMatrix[i] = new System.Timers.Timer() {
        Enabled = true,
        Interval = 10
    };

    timerMatrix[i].Elapsed += (sender, e) => {
        //TODO: add timer logic
    };
}
```

Comment: Elapsed not working.Error is => "Elapsed doesnt exist in the current context"

Comment: Sorry, missed the timer reference before elapsed, edited above

Comment: I need to write different code in each timers' elapsed event.How can I make this?

Comment: I've edited the sample above for you to provide an anonymous delegate. However, I'm struggling to see how useful this would be, I think you may need to provide more information as to what it is you hope to achieve with 40 timers? This will certainly initialize them and allow "something" to happen when they elapse, but I can't see how 40 generic actions is going to help in any situation...